# set functions and measures - trouble with definitions

Tags: measure-theory

Sorry, guys, this kind of question perhaps is too easy for you, but i really can't see where my mistake is.

Suppose we have a addtive set function $\mu$ defined on class of sets $\Sigma$ with range on the extended non-negative real values.

Immediately, we can conclude that, for every $E_i \in \Sigma$, $i=1,...,n$, $\mu(\cup_{i=1}^n E_i) \leq \mu(E_1) + ... + \mu(E_n)$

Now, suppose $\Sigma$ being a $ \sigma $-field and take a sequence $\{E_i\}_{i \geq 1}$. Why should i not conclude, by taking the limit over n in the above innequality, that $\mu(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_i)$ ?? (i'm thinking in left term as a monotone sequence $(a_n)$ and right term as a monotone sequence $(b_n)$ also. this should implies subadditivity or not?!? )

This question worries me, because in attempt to prove $\sigma$-additivity, the reverse innequality is get just by monotonicity of the additive non-negative set function. Also, i know we usually suppose regularity by borel sets to prove subadditivity, so, i know there exists a mistake here, but, as i said, i really cannot see where it is.

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Sigma$ be the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{P} ( \mathbb{R} )$, and let $\mu \colon \Sigma \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}_+$ be defined by:
\begin{align}
    \mu (A) = \begin{cases}
        0 &\text{if } A \text{ finite } \\
        +\infty &\text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{align}

Given disjoint subsets $E_1, \ldots, E_n$ of $\mathbb{R}$:

- either all of them are finite, in which case their union is also finite
- or one of them is infinite, and then the union is infinite

In both cases, we have
$$
\mu ( E_1 \cup \cdots \cup E_n ) = \mu ( E_1 ) + \cdots + \mu ( E_n )
$$

However, this cannot be extended to a countable number of subsets. Write $\mathbb{Q} = \cup_{r \in \mathbb{Q}}\ \{r\}$. Then $\mu (\mathbb{Q}) = +\infty$ since $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite, but

$$
    \sum_{r \in \mathbb{Q}} \mu (\{r\}) = \sum_{r \in \mathbb{Q}} 0 = 0
$$

Comment: This is not a measure

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out... I fixed this mistake by only mentioning finite additivité instead.